# Common collector

Tags: simulation, pspice, bandwidth, common-collector

I've created the following circuit in PSpice:

[image]

I was asked to simulate the circuit and create its Bode plot. I have done that and ended up with this :

[image]

I suspect that what I've got is incorrect because I'm supposed to calculate the bandwidth from the graph and if I change V<sub>ac</sub> to a smaller value, the value of V<sub>out</sub> in dB drops drastically. I've calculated analytically the bias point of each transistor and compared it to PSpice's results, and there was a complete match, so I have no idea what could be wrong with the circuit.

Comment: In the Y-axis, you only show a range of 0.2 dB (?). How is bandwidth defined? It has something to do with 3 dB? If you want more dBs drop then you need to simulate a .... frequency.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Yes I've increased the sweep range and could properly measure a voltage drop.